# 《 Machine Learning in Action》 code of Decision Tree hava TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python

Error in Decision Tree Code of Realizing << Machine Learning in Action>> 
The code is as follows

i copy the code from the book ,but when it's running It gives me this error

> line 9, in calcShannonEnt if curllabel not in labelCounts.keys():
>   TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

---

```
from  math import log
def calcShannonEnt(dataSet):
    numlen=len(dataSet)
    labelCounts={}
    for temp in dataSet:
        curllabel=temp[-1]
        if curllabel not in labelCounts.keys():
            labelCounts[curllabel] = 0
        labelCounts[curllabel]+=1
    shannonEnt=0.0

    for key in labelCounts:
        pro=float(labelCounts[key])/numlen
        shannonEnt-=pro*log(pro,2)
    return  shannonEnt

def createDataSet():
    dataSet = [[1, 1, 'yes'],
               [1, 1, 'yes'],
               [1, 0, 'no'],
               [0, 1, 'no'],
               [0, 1, 'no']]
    labels = ['no surfacing','flippers']
    #change to discrete values
    return dataSet, labels

dataset=createDataSet()
sl=calcShannonEnt(dataset)
print(sl)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataset=createDataSet()
```

should be

```
dataset,label=createDataSet()
```

done